# perl match string in 2d array

Tags: arrays, perl

Need to match a string in a 2D array and list the coordinates. 
eg. 
In the array below, I need to identify the position of the `'*'` in each row and columns. To make it simple assume that each row and column would have only one `'*'` element.

```
my @array = (
  [qw(* - -  - - -  - - -)],  #1
  [qw(- - -  * - -  - - -)],  #2
  [qw(- - -  - - -  * - -)],  #3

  [qw(- * -  - - -  - - -)],  #4
  [qw(- - -  - * -  - - -)],  #5
  [qw(- - -  - - -  - * -)],  #6

  [qw(- - *  - - -  - - -)],  #7
  [qw(- - -  - - *  - - -)],  #8
  [qw(- - -  - - -  - - *)],  #9
);
```

The expected result would be

```
Columns = {1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9}
Rows    = {1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9}
```

This example has symmetrical arrays but not all matrices necessarily will.

Comment: Why not use coordinates like `(1,1), (2,4), (3,7), .. ` and so on? According to you expected output coordinate `(4,4)` would be a star, but I think it should be `(2,4)` instead, right? (since in row 2, column 4, there is a star)

Answer (score 1):

One way: use linear index to identify elements' position, then rebuild row/column from that

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use List::MoreUtils qw(indexes);

my @matrix = ( ... );  # from the question

my @linear_idx = indexes { $_ eq '*' } map { @$_ } @matrix;

# Compute (row,col) points from linear indices (rectangular matrix)
my @pts = do {
    my $num_cols = @{$matrix[0]};
    map {
        my $row = int $_/$num_cols;
        [ $row + 1, $_ - $row*$num_cols + 1 ] 
    } @linear_idx;  
};

say "rows: ", join ',', map { $_->[0] } @pts;
say "cols: ", join ',', map { $_->[1] } @pts;
```

prints

```
rows: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
cols: 1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9
```

Comment: @el.pescado  Correct, just cleaned up and added a note.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @user1495523  There was an error which would make the solution wrong for  a rectangular matrix (it would only work for a square matrix). Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following

```
my ($x,$k)=(0,2);
foreach my $m (0..2)
{
    foreach my $i(0..$#array)
    {

        my @av = @{$array[$i]}[$x..$k]; 
        my $string = join("", @av );
        print $i+1 if($string=~m/\*/);

        #my @new_array = @{$array[$i]}[$x..$k];
        #foreach (@new_array)
        #{
        #   print   $i+1 if($_=~m/\*/);
        #}

    }
    $x+=3;
    $k+=3;
}   

print "\n";
```